# Observable return using observer

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, angular2-services

I'm trying to play with observables in Angular 2.
Here is my code:

```
public getJson<T>(uri: string): Observable<T> { 
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        this.refreshToken()
            .subscribe(token => {
                observer.next(
                    super.get<T>(this.getUrl(uri), <HttpOptions>this.getOptions())
                );
                observer.complete();
            });
    });  
    //return super.get<T>(this.getUrl(uri), <HttpOptions>this.getOptions());
}
```

Basically what I need to do is to call refreshToken() function and just after that call super.get......as in provided code.
All calls works good but there is only one problem, it returns data in wrong format like this: UseInf *{"_isScalar": false, "source": {}...... }*
So my question is, how to perform this: call refreshToken() function as first and then to call something like this>

**return super.get(this.getUrl(uri), this.getOptions());** /super is HttpClient/

Many thanks for any response!

**EDIT1**
I've also tried something like this:

```
public getJson<T>(uri: string): Observable<T> { 
    return this.refreshToken().map(response => {
        return super.get<T>(this.getUrl(uri), <HttpOptions>this.getOptions()); 
    })

}
```

but it give me error: *Type '`Observable<Observable<T>>`' is not assignable to type '`Observable<T>`*